# What causes floating poing number rounding in array?

Tags: c, floating-point

I have written this program to sort floating point array in C using bubble sort algorithm.

```
    /* This program will sort floating point numbers in an array */

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float fl_array[] = {12.35f, 14.05f, 9.85f, 14.34f, 2.58f, 36.6f}; 
    int array_length = sizeof(fl_array)/sizeof(fl_array[0]); 

    //printing the unsorted array
    int print_counter = 0;
    printf("Printing the unsorted array\n"); 
    do{
        printf("%.2f ", fl_array[print_counter]);
         print_counter ++; 
    } while(print_counter < array_length); 
    printf("\n"); 

    printf("***** Sorting Begins *********\n"); 

    //declaration of variables for sorting
    int i, j, temp_loc; 
    for(i=0; i<array_length; ++i)
    {
        for(j=i + 1; j<array_length; ++j)
        {
            if(fl_array[i] > fl_array[j])
            {
            temp_loc = fl_array[i]; 
            fl_array[i] = fl_array[j];
            fl_array[j]= temp_loc; 
            }
        }       
    }

    //end of bubble sort
    //prnting the sorted array

    print_counter = 0;
    printf("Printing the sorted array\n");
    do{
        printf("%.2f ", fl_array[print_counter]);
         print_counter ++; 
    } while(print_counter < array_length); 
    printf("\n");

return 0; 
}
```

The program produces the output as:

```
Printing the unsorted array
12.35 14.05 9.85 14.34 2.58 36.60 
***** Sorting Begins *********
Printing the sorted array
2.58 9.00 12.00 14.00 14.00 36.60
```

I have read many posts regarding this and I understand that floating point number cannot be directly processed, they could be converted to double and compared as a double value. But the question is what technique can be applied to this program to display the float numbers with their precision values?

Comment: @CoolGuy I don't think there is any undefined behavior in this program. You do realize that the innermost loop is entered only if its condition is true, right?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Oh. I missed that. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the `temp_loc` variable. It's an `int`, so assigning a float to it will convert it to an integer. Change it's type to `float`:

```
float temp_loc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. But why its printing 2.58 and 36.60 even when the data type of temp_loc is int? If it converts float to int it should convert all of them right? Anyway I made the correction and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Look at this line: `fl_array[i] = fl_array[j];` Probably `2.58` and `36.60` were just lucky guys and got swapped by this line, so they weren't assigned to `temp_loc` at all.

Comment: I wonder How carefully you observed the problem! Thanks. Give me some good tips for improvement.

Comment: Read the Bubble Sort article on Wikipedia and reimplement your algorithm **exactly** as described there. Afterwards, you can compare to an existing implementation.